# Multithread application in python flask

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, webserver, flask-socketio

I would like to ask same questions about the multithreading in python flask. Basically I have 3 files, where the first one is the main, second is thread and the last one is Flask webserver. What I want to achieve is to be able to control both "threads" from main. The AntBMS thread (second file) should be able to update the values in webserver. What I see now, that on connection the webserver creates a new thread. I think, that is not the right behaviour. At least when application terminates, it has to close all thread correctly.

```py
# app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode=None)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    pass
```

```py
# bms.py
from app import socketio
import configparser
import logging
import threading
import time

from random import random

BMS_CFG = 'bms.ini'

# set global logger
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
# set default options
config.read_dict(
    {
        'CORE': {
            'main_sleep_time': 5,
            'read_sleep_time': 5
        },
        'LOGGER': {
            'severity': logging.INFO
        },
        'WEBSERVER': {
            'host': '0.0.0.0',
            'port': 80,
            'debug': False
        }
    }
)
config.read(BMS_CFG)


def logger_init(log_level: int):
    """Function to init logger"""
    LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    stream = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream.setLevel(log_level)
    fmt = logging.Formatter('[%(levelname)s][%(threadName)s] %(message)s')
    stream.setFormatter(fmt)
    LOGGER.addHandler(stream)


logger_init(config.get('LOGGER', 'severity'))


class AntBMS():
    def __init__(self):
        LOGGER.debug("init")

    def run(self):
        LOGGER.info("Starting updating thread")
        try:
            while True:
                # just a random data for now
                t = round(random()*10, 3)
                socketio.emit('message', {'data': t}, namespace='/test')
                LOGGER.debug("Going to sleep for {}s".format(config.getint('CORE', 'main_sleep_time')))
                socketio.sleep(config.getint('CORE', 'main_sleep_time'))
        except Exception as ex:
            print("error: " + str(ex))
```

```py
# main.py
from app import app, socketio
from bms import AntBMS, config, LOGGER
import threading

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("start")

    ant = AntBMS()
    bms_thread = threading.Thread(target=ant.run, name="bms")
    bms_thread.start()

    socketio.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=80, debug=False, use_reloader=False)
    LOGGER.info("Stop")

    print("stop")
```

It works fine until I didn't connect :). As I've written I saw there a new thread-ID, so I guess, the thread has to be always the same. On the oder hand, it didn't correctly join the AntMBS thread.

```
Press CTRL+C to quit
[DEBUG][bms] Going to sleep for 5s
[DEBUG][bms] Going to sleep for 5s
^C[INFO][MainThread] Stop
stop
^CException ignored in: <module 'threading' from ...
 in _shutdown
    lock.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt:
```

So how to do it correctly?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using eventlet or gevent with your Socket.IO server? In that case, it is best to avoid using real threads and instead use the greenlets provided by these frameworks. Conversely, if using greenlets seems like a strange thing to do, then uninstall eventlet and gevent, so that your Socket.IO server reverts to standard threads, and then you can also use standard threads.

Comment: Uff, hard to say. But I think while I'm using the threads sperated from Socket.IO they have to be the standard one (from threading). Do you have the example how to integrate it with eventlet?

Comment: What is hard to say? If you are using eventlet or gevent? Do you have them installed? Remove them and try your application again. As I said before, if you are going to use threads combined with these packages, you have to understand the limitations, it is not as simple as just starting threads and hoping they'll work.

Comment: I mean by "hard to say", because there is not "eventlet" or "gevent" using. But I read, that it's depending if it's installed. It automatically load the eventlet if they are installed. (In my case not.) Looks like that it ins't necessary to use the concept like I wrote. Maybe I can get rid of it. I have to really verify it first.